# Getting MalformedURLException when using inputStream in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, inputstream

So I'm writing some unit tests using JUnit for an RSS parser application.  The part I'm trying to test takes a URL and opens a connection to it (HttpURLConnection), then passes an inputStream of this into a parser (connection.getInputStream()).  Once in the parser, creates a new XMLEventReader from the input stream.

I'm trying to replicate this process within my JUnit tests by having a local XML file of the same structure as the RSS feed would be.  When I try to load this in using:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/localXmlFile.xml");
```

I get a MalformedURLException thrown when this line of the parser is hit:

```
XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(inputStream);
```

Can anyone shed any light as to how I would correctly replicate the functionality within my tests?  Is this something we would use EasyMock for (I don't know as I've never used it).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(inputStream);` is throwing MalformedURLException because based on [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#createXMLEventReader%28java.io.InputStream%29), that API throws XMLStreamException. It almost seems to me that your JUnit tests have some dangling `URL` objects that cause MalformedURLException.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you should have

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("localXmlFile.xml");
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, but still getting the exception.  Thanks for the suggestion though.